# Subspace of another subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a vector space V and two subspaces H and K and I have shown H+K is a subspace of  V and now I want to prove that H and K are subspaces of H+K

Does it suffice to say it contains the zero vector and is stable under linear combination??

And If so does it mean whenever I have two subspaces A and B of V

A subset of B always implies A subspace of B???

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are right: if $A,B$ are subspaces of $V$, and $A\subseteq B$ then $A$ is a subspace of  $B$. And to prove this you only need to say: $A\subseteq B$, $0\in A$ (by the fact $A$ is a subspace of $V$), and if $a_1,a_2\in A$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are scalars then $\lambda_1 a_1 +\lambda_2 a_2\in A$ (by the fact $A$ is a subspace of $V$). The special case about $H,K$ and $H+K$ follows as you suggest.

Comment: @ancientmathematician thanks so much